# How react.js state works?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am about to learn React.js and I really like the state management so far.
But how does it actually work technically? Does it use cookies or browser storage?

Comment: See this [link](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/react-state-management.md).

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 1):

> Does it use cookies or browser storage?

No. Just variables/properties. Component state doesn't persist between reloads.